# Why is the comparing instruction not working?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So I have a simple assembly code in 8086 that compares the value in the variable *value* with 100 and if it's greater it prints out: "The value is greater than 100" and if not: "The value is not greater than 100".

Here is the code:

```
data segment
    string db "The value is larger$"
    value db 80
    right db "The value is greater than 100$"
    wrong db "The value is not greater than 100$"
ends

stack segment
    dw 128 dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    lea ax, value
    cmp ax, 100d
    jae StatementWrong

StatementRight:
    lea dx, right
    jmp Ending

StatementWrong:
    lea dx, wrong

Ending:
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

ends
```

However the problem is no matter what value I have, whether it be larger or not than 100, the *StatementRight* segment is always being executed.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: `lea ax, value` is an inefficient way to do `mov ax, OFFSET value`, putting the address in AX, not the contents of the memory location.  Your cmp/jae depends on the address, not the value.

Comment: LEA = Load Effective ***Address***. AX will not contain 80 (or anything else you put in 'value'), but its address.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> lea ax, value
> cmp ax, 100d
> jae StatementWrong
> ```

### 3 instructions, all 3 wrong!

The `lea` instruction loads the address of the *value* variable. You need its content. You get this with either of next instructions:

```
mov al, value
```

or

```
mov al, [value]
```

---

Since your *value* variable is defined to be a byte, your code should also compare it as a byte.

```
cmp al, 100
```

---

The message that belongs to *StatementWrong* reads : "The value is **not** greater than 100". Why then do you *jump to this message* when the comparison produced ABOVE OR EQUAL ? That's contradictory.

```
jng StatementWrong
```

### --------------------------------------------

In context (and improved a little!):

```
  mov  al, [value]
  cmp  al, 100
  lea  dx, right    ; "The value is greater than 100$"
  jg   Ending       ; JG means JUMP IF GREATER
  lea  dx, wrong    ; "The value is not greater than 100$"
Ending:
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue is that you're declaring value as BYTE, but loading a WORD into AX. There are several solutions to this, but the simples one would be;

```
    cmp     al, 100
```

or

```
value:   dw   100
```

that way the high order of AX is zeroed and using **CMP AX** works.

Comment: The code isn't loading from memory at all, though, it's using LEA to get the address.  So you've missed a large part of the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes No I haven't missed anything, I've just elected not to reiterate what you and tevemadar illuded to via a comment, so if OP made those changes, then this would be the next issue.

Comment: Answers are supposed to stand on their own, or at least *mention* what they're building on.

Comment: I see where the problem arises. The first word of this response was supposed to be Another not The as it was my intention to embellish upon what was already commented on.

Comment: You still haven't fixed your answer.  That's what the [edit] button is for.  Don't just comment after you figure out what went wrong, fix the answer.  Or delete it because there's already a complete answer.  (And BTW, comments aren't meant to be permanent answers.  If you post an answer, leaving out things that were only mentioned in comments is not ok.)  I sometimes just leave comments on questions I don't think will have much/any future value to future readers, but if you are going to answer then do it right.